# Polymer iron-form validate at least one checkbox is checked

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0

I'm using the iron-form component with Polymer, and trying to validate if at least one checkbox in a group of checkboxes is checked.

When I call submit() on an iron-form the validate function is called. How would I add the custom validation rules to to make sure at least one checkbox is checked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length` to get the number of `checkboxes` checked.

If the value is `0`, show/alert error message and prevent the form from being submitted.

```js
var myForm = document.getElementById('myForm');
myForm.addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
  var no_of_cb_checked = myForm.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').length;
  if (no_of_cb_checked == 0) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('Select atleast one checkbox');
  }
});
```

```html
<form id='myForm'>
<input type='checkbox' name='form1' value='CB1'>CB1
<input type='checkbox' name='form1' value='CB2'>CB2
<input type='checkbox' name='form1' value='CB3'>CB3
<input type='checkbox' name='form1' value='CB4'>CB4
<input type='submit'>
</form>
```